# Remove taxonomy name and add .html extension in the custom taxonomy term URL

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I just created a custom taxonomy "product category" for the default post type. My taxonomy works perfectly fine. However, the URL for the term is not what I want.

For example, I have a "Light" term in "product category" taxonomy.
The current URL for "Light" page is: `http://mywebsite.com/product-category/light/`
What I expect is: `http://mywebsite.com/light.html`

Here is my code for the taxonomy register in function.php

```
function product_category_register_taxonomy() {

  $args = array (
    'label' => esc_html__( 'Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
    'labels' => array(
        'menu_name' => esc_html__( 'Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'all_items' => esc_html__( 'All Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'edit_item' => esc_html__( 'Edit Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'view_item' => esc_html__( 'View Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'update_item' => esc_html__( 'Update Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'add_new_item' => esc_html__( 'Add new Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'new_item_name' => esc_html__( 'New Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'parent_item' => esc_html__( 'Parent Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => esc_html__( 'Parent Product Category:', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'search_items' => esc_html__( 'Search Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'popular_items' => esc_html__( 'Popular Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => esc_html__( 'Separate Product Category with commas', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => esc_html__( 'Add or remove Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => esc_html__( 'Choose most used Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'not_found' => esc_html__( 'No Product Category found', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'name' => esc_html__( 'Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
        'singular_name' => esc_html__( 'Product Category', 'Product Category Taxonomy' ),
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => false,
    'rest_base' => false,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'sort' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product-category','with_front' => true)
  );

  register_taxonomy( 'product-category', array( 'post' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'product_category_register_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Comment: Can you provide some context as to **why** you're doing this? What problem does this solve for you? Note that the behaviour you're getting is expected behaviour, and adding `.html` to the end conveys zero advantages ( especially not SEO )

Comment: @TomJNowell I have some blogs which are written for the different product categories. Therefore, I would like to assign these blogs to the customized categories. Also, I won't have a "Product Category" page to maintain all the terms like "Light"... Each term will act as a root category. That's why I want to remove "product-category" from the URL.

Comment: I still don't understand why `.html` is needed, perhaps you should break this apart into 2 separate questions? The part about removing the taxonomy from the name has hundreds of people who ask that question with tonnes of answers on the site